# __doPostBack seems not working in an external JS file

Tags: javascript, dopostback

As the title mention I have a separated JS file that interarcts with my ASP.Net page. At the begining, all the JS function were inside the ASP.Net page including the __doPostBack method and all was working OK. But, once I moved the JS functions to a separated file to keep up my page clear all the functions were working as normal except the one that use the __doPostBack.

Now I can't call my C# function from codebihind 'cause the __doPostBack is not executed.

So, Does anyone of you know if this method works in a separeated JS file? If so, waht would be the correct code to execute it? Or Do I need to maintain it in the same file where my ASP.Net code is?

Thanks for your help in advance
Regards!

Comment: Should be no problem.  __doPostBack is exposed as JS function to your front end. It is supposed to be defined in a specific way at front end along the lines of this: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/ . It should be defined pretty early I suppose so as soon as possible in your HTML in one of the first JS or directly in HTML. As for calling it it should be callable ANYWHERE if it is defined as a global variable of __doPostback for instance inline in your HTML then it doesn't matter which JS calls it. Should still work. Otherwise, u need to post code to find out issue.

Comment: if you want to define it in external JS , in your testing you should call as soon as possible, is probably better to define it immediately and globally then you can call it anywhere in your testing. If you define __doPostBack in external js file, that external js should be the FIRST to be loaded from the HTML page in the script src reference, so it should be the  VERY FIRST ONE, and the JS definition itself needs to expose __doPostBack function globally so window["__doPostBack"] = function(){} so it can be called anywhere successfully if you have to DEFINE it in external JS. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi sajawikio.

I did what you commented and it's working OK now. Before the references to the external JS file and before to call the function that execute the __doPostBack, I declared a global variable in my ASP.Net page as: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> var pageId = '<%= Page.ClientID %>'; </script>.